# React - How to target a specific component instance

Tags: reactjs

Noob question...

I have dynamically created functional component instances, how do I alter state on one specific instance? Say the third one, change "rat" to "mouse"?
If I had done this with AS3 I would have put the instances inside an array and then been able to address them from the array index, how is it done with React?

```
const display_set = ["cat","dog","rat","bat"];

function drawDisplay() {
    return (
      <div className="Row-display">
        {display_set.map((displayItem, index) => (
          <DisplayComponent
         id={index}

          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }


import React, { useState } from "react";

function DisplayComponent(props) {
  return <button>id {props.id}</button>;
}

export default DisplayComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DrawDisplay` component should accept the array as a prop (component names *must* start with a capital letter, so `drawDisplay` will not work):

```
function DrawDisplay(props) {
  return (
    <div className="Row-display">
      {props.items.map((displayItem, index) => (
        <DisplayComponent
       id={index}
         />
       ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then the parent component should pass in the array as a prop:

```
function MyParentComponent() {
  return <DrawDisplay items={["cat","dog","rat","bat"]} />
}
```

To change the items, the parent component needs some way to pass in a different array:

```
function MyParentComponent() {
  const [animals, setAnimals] = useState(["cat","dog","rat","bat"])

  const changeRat = () => {
    // make a new array with "rat" replaced with "mouse"
    const newAnimals = animals.map(animal => animal === "rat" ? "mouse" : animal);
    // replace the state with the new array
    setAnimals(newAnimals)
  }

  return <>
   <button onClick={changeRat}>Change "rat" to "mouse"</button>
   <DrawDisplay items={animals} />
  </>
}
```

I recommend reading the React documentation, specifically these articles (these links go to a version of the React docs that use function components with hooks, rather than class components):

- [Components and props](https://reactwithhooks.netlify.app/docs/components-and-props.html)
- [State and lifecycle](https://reactwithhooks.netlify.app/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Fabulous thank you Stephen. So the mindset is to think of the instances only in terms of state and props? So the four instances cannot be affected in any other way? Do I have that correct?

Comment: For the most part, yes. To "make" another component do something, the solution is usually "pass data in as a prop", or "[call a callback function that was passed in as a prop](https://reactwithhooks.netlify.app/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up)".